# Stored Procedure Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've got two stored procedures:

## SP1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAge

@Birthday datetime,
@BirthDayAge INT OUTPUT

AS

SELECT @BirthDayAge = YEAR(GETDATE()-DATEPART(dy, @Birthday) + 1)-YEAR(@Birthday);
```

## SP2

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AgeProc

@Age int

AS

DECLARE @BirthDayAge INT;
EXEC GetAge @Age, @BirthDayAge OUTPUT

SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE @BirthdayAge  = @Age;
```

For some reason or other, no results are being returned in the second procedure when tested. Am I doing something wrong in either of the stored procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 WHERE @BirthdayAge  = @Age;
```

you are comparing 2 variables.

Shouldnt one of this be a table column?

also, you are passing an integer to a datetime, that may cause issues

Comment: I'm trying to compare the output from SP1 to the 'Age' variable.

Comment: but that doesnt make sense, you will end up with 2 situations, on the first, both variables will be the same and you will return all columns in the table (because you will have select * from .... where 5=5, thats TRUE to all rows), second, they would be different and it wont return any rows

Comment: I think you want SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE BirthdayAge  = @Age;

Comment: I ended up using another approach. Thanks for the help nonetheless.